# Derivative of integral of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be a smooth function and let
$$g(x)=\int_0^x(a+\epsilon 1_{\{y=0\}})f(y)dy$$

Then, is it true that
$$g(x)=a\int_0^x f(y)dy$$

Since the second term is zero except at one point.

But if we use the first expression of $g(x)$,
$$g'(x)=(a+\epsilon 1_{\{x=0\}})f(x)$$
but if we use the second one
$$g'(x)=af(x)$$
Can anyone explain where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for each $x\in\Bbb{R}$, we have  $g(x)=a\int_0^xf(y)\,dy$ (since the Lebesgue measure of singletons is zero), so for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $g’(x)=af(x)$ by the FTC (since $f$ is continuous, since you’re even assuming $f$ is smooth).

For the first integrand, in general, $F:=(a+\epsilon\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}})f$ is only continuous on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ so if you insist on using the FTC with $F$ as the integrand, then all you can say is that since $F$ is continuous away from the origin, for all $x\in\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, $g’(x)=F(x)=af(x)$. But at the origin, if $f(0)\neq 0$ (which is the generic case), then $F$ is not continuous at the origin, so the FTC can’t be applied at the origin, and in particular, you cannot say that $g’(0)=F(0)$. This would be wrong; the correct conclusion is already in my first paragraph: $g’(0)=af(0)$.

No contradictions anywhere. You just have to be careful to only use theorems when they are actually applicable.

Comment: So $g'(0)$ is not well defined?

Comment: @abc I never said that. In fact my very first line said $g’(x)=af(x)$ (for all $x$). So $g’(0)=af(0)$. If you decide to use the integrand $F=(a+\epsilon\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}})f$, then yes, $g(x)=\int_0^xF(y)\,dy$, but (barring some trivial edge cases) you CANNOT conclude that $g’(0)=F(0)$. Anyway, I have rephrased slightly to be more explicit with what we can vs can’t say.

Answer (score 0):

We can figure this out by considering when x=0 and x>0. If f is a smooth function, then af is also a smooth function but (a+epsilon)f is not smooth anymore. But there's only this one point that this function is not continuous so we can regard this function as af+const when x=0. So we can't use the first expression to get g'

Comment: But g is defined by the first expression. The second one is implied by the first one.